# Firebase post an array of data with auto generated ID using restful api

Tags: firebase, rest-firebase

[Firebase REST API doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html) has an example of posting a list of data:

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  "author": "alanisawesome",
  "title": "The Turing Machine"
}' 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/posts.json'
```

the keys are provided in the posted data. Is it possible to just post a list of values and have firebase auto-generate the keys, similar to the javascript example below?

```
var postsRef = ref.child("posts");
  postsRef.push({
    author: "gracehop",
    title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
  });
  postsRef.push({
    author: "alanisawesome",
    title: "The Turing Machine"
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase REST API creates one child node for every POST request you send.

The JavaScript snippet you show does the same, it creates one child each time you call `push`. It's just more efficient, since it only has to establish a connection once, while the REST API sets up a new connection for every request.

You can get the result you're looking for by generating the IDs client-side (the algorithm that Firebase uses to generate its Push IDs is described in [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html)) and then issuing a [HTTP PATCH request](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-patch).